# plt.show and plt.savefig give different result

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my code, and i get different result from plt.savefig and plt.show

I have trid to use the bbox_inches='tight', but that makes the picture size become not exactly 700*400.

```
x=np.linspace(1*13,20*13,20)
ys=[[9.429781134779862, 5.29464711177, 3.607607723166614, 2.899937651340496, 2.191804841696895, 1.9843671555485882, 1.7248100121771586, 1.3670895074513212, 1.3698780260605596, 1.2462146230823874, 1.1289892836337199, 1.032841253332204, 0.9543441746831577, 0.7484693801176594, 0.8376893177858197, 0.7849478402160176, 0.7434280956345902, 0.7000987139186625, 0.665212069607791, 0.6300403225806451], [126.98106331402796, 53.50512044002611, 30.074826167504753, 24.227858160427186, 16.471886607532593, 14.13705307473836, 11.449887848348526, 8.72965989245059, 8.840716805318575, 7.263008047412916, 6.293385023002322, 5.634501177610746, 4.6241919224615495, 3.9431399223201433, 3.937845053672828, 3.578854694920532, 3.3610282057487026, 2.947140095251568, 2.629807287721956, 2.5260498894853174]]
plt.figure(figsize=(7,4))
plt.plot(x, ys[0], marker='o',markersize=10,  label='original method')
plt.plot(x, ys[1], marker='s',markersize=10,   label='our method')

plt.xlabel('Number of trajectories(×1000)',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel("QPS",fontsize=20)  
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xticks(fontsize=15)
plt.yticks(fontsize=15)
plt.legend(fontsize=20)
plt.savefig("../res/dense.png",dpi=plt.gcf().dpi)
plt.show()
```

This is the two pictures I got from savefig() and show()

[image: savefig gives me this]

[image: show gives me this]

Comment: Can you use `plt.show()` before `plt.savefig("../res/dense.png",dpi=plt.gcf().dpi)` and check ?

Comment: @Hayat oooo, that solves the problem! but what is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

`plt.show()` before

`plt.savefig("../res/dense.png",dpi=plt.gcf().dpi)`

It's just a matter of convention. When we call `plt.savefig` the reference of all the variable point till `plt.savefig` after that any statement it corresponds to new plot.

You can accept the answer. If it helps.