# plt.show() and plt.savefig() how to save plt.show() image without showing using plt.show()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This question is a continuation for this question below

[plt.show and plt.savefig give different result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639159/plt-show-and-plt-savefig-give-different-result)

By putting `plt.show()` infront of `plt.savefig()`, the plot and save image would be the same.

Is there a way to save the figure which is after `plt.show()` but not using the `plt.show()` function due to the blocking it have?

Tried putting `block=false` but it wont save the same as the `plt.show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `plt.ion()`, this turns on interactive mode for matplotlib.  The image will open and the code keeps running.

Answer (score 0):

The plot should come up in a separate tab (at least it does on Spyder). There should be a save button on this here and you can easily save it from there. It should allow multiple plots (if you have them) to be generated and then saved.

The save button is in the top right hand corner.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is looking for a way to do this programmatically, i.e. not via the GUI

Comment: I'm only trying to provide a helpful alternative